# JQuery dynamic ID control property

Tags: jquery, dynamic, controls

So, I have JQuery dynamically generating controls. The input controls are called EnterLink + number of controls generated. On generation of a new input control I want to change the previously created input so it is disabled. Right now my code looks as so, it does not work.

```
if (rowCount > 0) {
                   var last = rowCount - 1;
                  $("#EnterLink" + last).disabled = true;
                  }
```

This looks like it should work, I checked the ids of the controls and that's exactly like they are formatted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$("#EnterLink" + last).disabled = true;
```

With this:

```
$("#EnterLink" + last).attr('disabled', true);
```

jQuery does not expose the regular DOM attributes directly through its `$()` function. What you have there is a wrapped set (that, granted, will only ever match 1 element but is a set nonetheless) that extends the elements and adds all the jQuery goodness to it.

If you wanted to get the native DOM element of `#EnterLinkX`, you would do this:

```
$("#EnterLink" + last)[0].disabled = true;
```

This works because the return value of `$()` is an array-like structure that contains the matched elements. `[0]` would contain the first (and in this case only) match. This would then give you access to stuff like `innerHTML` and such. 99% of the time, though, you are better off doing it the "jQuery way" as that's the whole point of the library. In this case, you would use it's [`attr`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr) function to set the attribute, and it's [`removeAttr`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/removeAttr#name) function to remove the disabled value if you ever wanted to.

Comment: Gracias! 15characterlimitstinks

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to disable a button it's the following.

$("#EnterLink" + last).attr( "disabled", true );
or
$("#EnterLink" + last).attr( "disabled", "disabled" );

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Alternative_Resources
Has everything you need for jquery development.